# Using an external regex library from AWK

Tags: regex, awk, regex-greedy

My question is inspired by an interesting [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116036/automatically-replace-all-foo-with-absfoo/116304?noredirect=1#comment257932_116304) somebody asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com and my attempt to provide the AWK solution. Note AWK here means NAWK since as we know `gawk != awk`. I am reproducing a bit of that answer here.

**Original question:**

I have a rather large document with lots of math notation. I've used `|foo|` throughout to indicate the absolute value of foo. I'd like to replace every instance of `|foo|` with `\abs{foo}`, so that I can control the notation via an abs macro I define.

**My answer:**

This post is inspired by **cmhughes** proposed solutions. His post is one of the most interesting posts on TeX editing which I have ever read. I just spent 2 hours trying to produce nawk solution. During that process I learned  that AWK not only doesn't support non-greedy regular expressions which is to be expected since it is sed's cousin but even worse AWK regular expression does not capture its groups.
A simple AWK script

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR>0{
gsub(/\|([^|]*)\|/,"\\abs{\1}")
print
}
```

Applied to the file

```
$|abs|$ so on and so fourth
$$|a|+|b|\geq|a+b|$$
who is affraid of wolf $|abs|$
```

will unfortunately produce

```
$\abs{}$ so on and so fourth
$$\abs{}+\abs{}\geq\abs{}$$
who is affraid of wolf $\abs{}$
```

An obvious fix for above solution is to use **gawk**  instead as in

```
awk '{print gensub(/\|([^|]*)\|/, "\\abs{\\1}", "g", $0)}'
```

However I wonder if there is a way to use an external **regex** library from 
AWK for example [tre](http://laurikari.net/tre/). Even more generally how does one interface AWK with
the C code (the pointer to documentation would be OK).

Comment: The simple and straightforward solution would seem to be to switch to Perl. There is a script `a2p` in the Perl distribution which converts Awk scripts to equivalent Perl scripts, which may help if you prefer a slow learning curve and near-immediate results over pretty, maintainable, idiomatic Perl code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `nawk`, the answer is: not without modifying the source.

Two of the problems are:

- regular expressions are part of the language (`~` and `//`), as well as the defined language functions (`match()` etc.)
- `nawk` uses its own regex code (in the file `b.c`) so unlike a program which uses one regex library, using a different library with alternate implementations of `regcomp()` `regexec()` will not help.

One way `gawk` has approached this is to extend `match()` with a [third argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). (There's also `gensub()` as you note, but I try to avoid it where possible.)

`gawk` also supports [loadable extensions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-API-Description.html), which would be a way to interface with a PCRE library to provide new "builtin" functions (though not replace `~` or any internal functions). This API is the new "4.1" way of doing extensions, previous versions had a substantially different implementation.

Finally, one `nawk` way to achieve the required substitution is:

```
match($0,/\|[^|]*\|/) {
    do {
        sub(/\|[^|]*\|/,"\\abs{" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) "}",$0)
    } while (match($0,/\|[^|]*\|/))
}
{ print }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my nawk based solution using split function:

```
awk '{
   split($0, arr, "|");
   for (i=1; i<=length(arr); i++) {
      if (i%2)
         printf("%s", arr[i]);
      else
         printf("\\abs{%s}", arr[i]);
   }
   printf("%s", ORS)
}' file
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$\abs{abs}$ so on and so fourth
$$\abs{a}+\abs{b}\geq\abs{a+b}$$
who is affraid of wolf $\abs{abs}$
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/lMf2hL